# Add padding that’s reflected in the height of parent, using display: inline

Tags: css

I’m sure somebody has had this problem before, but I can’t seem to find the right way of describing it.

I’ve got a row of icons like so:

[image: Row of icons]

Which is produced like so...

HTML:

```
<nav class="nav-global">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/our-story">Our Story</a>
        </li>
        ...
        <li>
            <a href="/login">Login</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-global ul {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-global li {
  display: inline;
}
  .nav-global li a {
    background-image: url(/try/img/nav-global-icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 0;
  }
```

My problem happens when I want to add padding to the top of the `<a>` to get the icons to sit on top.

By adding `padding-top: 35px;` to `.nav-global li a`:

[image: Row of icons broken]

Here’s what the inspector is telling me:

[image: Inspector]

I’ve tried using `inline-block`, tried making the `<a>` `display: block`, using `clearfix` and a few other things but can’t seem to figure it out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should also try adding padding to li element (.nav-global li), and display it as inline-block

```
.nav-global li {
   display: inline-block;
   padding-top: 35px;
}
```